# Set value to a textview in the activity

Tags: android, android-layout

On the event invocation of an activity, I opened an AlertDialog.Builder which lists an array of single choice items. When the user clicks any item, I want to set the same to a text view in the activity.

```
I tried this:
Activity class:
public MyActivity extends Activity implements onClickListener {
     TextView item;
     public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        item = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_item);
        item .setOnClickListener(this);
     }
     public void onClick(View v) {
          new MyBuilder(this).show();
          updateUI();
     }
     private void updateUI() {
          item.setText(ItemMap.item);
     }
}

Builder class: 

public class MyBuilder extends AlertDialog.Builder implements OnClickListener{

Context context;
String[] items = {"pen", "pencil", "ruler"};
public MyBuilder(Context context) {
    super(context);
    super.setTitle("Select Item");
    this.context = context;
    super.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
    ItemMap.item = items[position];
    dialog.dismiss();
}
}

Mapping class: 

public class ItemMap {
    public static String item;
}
```

Here, MyBuilder is a subclass extending AlertDialog.Builder
updateUI() tries to set the value which user chooses from the list of items. But it did not work! updateUI() is called soon after the dialog is shown.

Could anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see the modified source!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `updateUI()` in the current location, you are trying to access `ItemMap.item` before it is set in the `AlertDialog.Builder`.  You're going to need some way to call back from the `onClick` in the `AlertDialog.Builder` to your main class - I would do it by adding an interface and then passing that in to your builder - like this:

Activity class:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity implements onClickListener, AlertBuilderCallback {
     TextView item;
     public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        item = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_item);
        item .setOnClickListener(this);
     }
     public void onClick(View v) {
          new MyBuilder(this).addCallback(this).show();
          updateUI();
     }
     public void updateUI() {
          item.setText(ItemMap.item);
     }
}
```

AlertBuilderCallback interface:

```
public interface AlertBuilderCallback {
    public void updateUI();
}
```

Builder class:

```
 public class MyBuilder extends AlertDialog.Builder implements OnClickListener{

    Context context;
    String[] items = {"pen", "pencil", "ruler"};
    public MyBuilder(Context context) {
        super(context);
        super.setTitle("Select Item");
        this.context = context;
        super.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, this);
    }

    public MyBuilder addCallback(AlertBuilderCallback callBack) {
        this.callBack = callBack;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
        ItemMap.item = items[position];
        if(this.callBack != null) {
            this.callBack.updateUI();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Mapping class:

```
public class ItemMap {
    public static String item;
}
```

Comment: No problems - an interesting point to note about this approach is that we are keeping the builder design pattern going with this additional method in your `Mybuilder` class by returning the actual builder itself.  Have a read on on the Builder design pattern (http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder), and design patterns in general (http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns) if you  aren't familiar with them.

Answer (score 0):

move the updateUI() from MyActivity onClick(), to onClick for Dialog.

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {
   ItemMap.item = items[position];
   updateUI();
   dialog.dismiss();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a load of things wrong here.  You could move the `updateUI()` in to the onClick in your Activity, which should work, but here's another few things to think about:

1. Why is your AlertDialog.Builder in a different class?  this is alright if you are going to extend it with some extra behaviour and use it in other places in your application - if if you are only using it here then you should declare it inside your activity.
2. Why is your ItemMap.item static?  Is that a design decision?

Comment: Yes, I'm extending the same behaviour in some part of the application. And keeping ItemMap.item static is a design decision.

Comment: OK - just wanted to make sure :)  I'll add a new answer detailing how you can solve this